# retrieving data from sqlite in blackberry java

Tags: java, sqlite, blackberry

i need to retrieve data from sqlite .and retrieved data should be displayed in a gridfieldmanager layout.i have done the below code please help me how to display data from database over the myscreen.

### SQLManager screen

```
 public class SQLManager {
static String snapsdata;
private static String DB_NAME = "employee_details.db3";

   private Database _db;

  public SQLManager() throws Exception {

    // Determine if an SDCard is present
    boolean sdCardPresent = false;
    String root = null;
    Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        root = (String) e.nextElement();
        if (root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/")) {
            sdCardPresent = true;
        }
    }

    if (!sdCardPresent) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("This application requires an SD card to be 
 present.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    } else {
        String dbLocation = "/SDCard/databases/sample/";

        // Create URI
        URI uri = URI.create(dbLocation + DB_NAME);

        // Open or create a plain text database. This will create the
        // directory and file defined by the URI (if they do not already
        // exist).
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri,
                new DatabaseSecurityOptions(false));

        // Close the database in case it is blank and we need to write to
        // the file
        db.close();
        //Dialog.alert("db");
        // Open a connection to the database file
        FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection) Connector
                .open("file://" + dbLocation + DB_NAME);

        // If the file is blank, copy the pre-defined database from this
        // module to the SDCard.
        if (fileConnection.exists() && fileConnection.fileSize() == 0) {

            readAndWriteDatabaseFile(fileConnection);
            //Dialog.alert("db1");
        }

        // Open the database
        db = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
        _db = db;
    }
}

/**
 * Copies the pre-defined database from this module to the location
 * specified by the fileConnection argument.
 * 
 * @param fileConnection
 *            File connection to the database location
 */
    public void readAndWriteDatabaseFile(FileConnection fileConnection)
        throws IOException {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    // Open an input stream to the pre-defined encrypted database bundled
    // within this module.
    inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + DB_NAME);
    //Dialog.alert("db" + inputStream);
    // Open an output stream to the newly created file
    outputStream = (OutputStream) fileConnection.openOutputStream();

    // Read data from the input stream and write the data to the
    // output stream.
    byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 5];
    int length = 0;
    while (-1 != (length = inputStream.read(data))) {
        outputStream.write(data, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the connections
    if (fileConnection != null) {
        fileConnection.close();
    }
    if (outputStream != null) {
        outputStream.close();
    }
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Constructs a new SQLManager object
 * 
 * @param db
 *            Database to manage
 */
public SQLManager(Database db) {
    _db = db;
}

/**
 * Closes the database
 */
void closeDB() {
    try {
        _db.close();

    } catch (DatabaseException dbe) {

    }
}

public void SaveEmployeeInformation(int employeeid, String employee_name,   
String position, int salary){


    //return productinfo;
    Statement st;
    try {
        st = _db.createStatement("INSERT INTO 
 employee_details(employee_id,employee_name,position,salary) VALUES (?, ?, 
 ?, ?)");

     try
     {
         st.prepare();
         Object[] bindParams = {new Integer(employeeid), new 
 String(employee_name), new String(position), new Integer(salary)};
         long rowID = st.executeInsert(bindParams);
        // Dialog.alert("ro "+rowID);
     }
     finally
     {
         st.close();
         closeDB();
     }
    } catch (DatabaseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Vector getEmployeeInformation(){
    Vector productinfo = new Vector();
    try {
        Statement statement = null;
        // Read in all records from the Category table

        statement = _db
                .createStatement("select MAX(employee_id) as 
  employeeReportId from employee_details");
        // ProjectImagesID Project_id,ImagePath,ImageDescription
        statement.prepare();

        // statement.setCursorBufferSize(10);

        Cursor cursor = statement.getCursor();
        Employeelist productdatas;

        Row row;

        // Iterate through the result set. For each row, create a new
        // Category object and add it to the hash table.
        while (cursor.next()) {
            row = cursor.getRow();

            productdatas = new Employeelist(row.getInteger(0));

            productinfo.addElement(productdatas);

        }
    //  Dialog.alert(""+productinfo.size());
        statement.close();
        cursor.close();

    } catch (DatabaseException dbe) {
        Dialog.alert("SD PRODUCTINFP  " + dbe.toString());
    } catch (DataTypeException e) {
        Dialog.alert("PRODUCTINFP  " + e.toString());
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeDB();
    }

    return productinfo;
}
}
```

### myscreen screen

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
/**
 * Creates a new MyScreen object
 */
public  MyScreen()
{        
    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("MyTitle");
   // int reportid = 0;
    try {
        SQLManager emp = new SQLManager();
        emp.SaveEmployeeInformation(7,"farah","developer", 4000);
        emp.getEmployeeInformation();
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int row = 5;
      GridFieldManager  dfm = new GridFieldManager(row,3, 0);

                  add(dfm);        

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to acheive the successul set up and retreiving of data from SQlite Db. .Then with retrieved data,try to use it in grid field Manager.

Please write exact problem in code which helps us to solvethe problem.

Comment: with great difficulty i am now able to get data from database but now my problem is i dont know how to create gridfield and how to place retrieved data from database in gridfield.

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_grid_layout_877557_11.jsp Check this link